# Remove Date and Time from lock-screen

Tags: lumia, settings, 8.1, lock-screen

I am using Nokia Luima 520 with windows 8.1.10 version. From the lock screen I wish to remove date and time. It is only because I am huge bing fan and like most of the images offered by bing to it's users.

Any trick I can be helped with in order to get rid of the date and time from the lock screen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is **not** possible in the current *Developer Preview* of Windows Phone 8.1.

The public release of Windows Phone 8.1 will feature **lock screen theming apps**, and these apps may contain that feature.

Answer (score -1):

Set the lock screen image to a white one and the date and time will disappear.

Comment: Not a very useful suggestion, considering the OP wants to use Bing's daily images on the lockscreen.

Comment: No, it's not. But it works :)